# How to run a asyncTask on click of a particular word of a text in TextView

Tags: android, textview

Hi guys I want to know that whether i can run a Async task on click of a particular word of a text in TextView.basically I have a Textview below and I want to highlight "RESEND" word & run asynctask on click of it .Do I have to create separate textview with text"RESEND" or there is some shortcut bcoz if i make separate Texview,it will not look like 2 textviews are 1.It will look different whether i use verticle or horizontal

```
   <TextView
                android:id="@+id/policy"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:layout_weight="4.5"
                android:text="If you haven&apos;t receive the verification code,tap RESEND"
                android:textColor="#000"
                android:textSize="@dimen/txtss" />
```

Answer (score 0):

android.text.style.ClickableSpan can solve you problem.

```
SpannableString ss = new SpannableString("If you haven&apos;t receive the verification code,tap RESEND");
ClickableSpan clickableSpan = new ClickableSpan() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View textView) {

            //Start your async here           

    }
    @Override
    public void updateDrawState(TextPaint ds) {
            super.updateDrawState(ds);
            ds.setUnderlineText(false);
        }
};
//p1 is index of R in RESEND, p2 is index of D in RESEND
ss.setSpan(clickableSpan, p1, p2, Spanned.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);

TextView textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.policy);
textView.setText(ss);
```

Answer (score 0):

you can define the textview property clickable in xml file as-

```
android:clickable="true"
```

and

```
android:onClick="clickHandler"
```

then inside your activity class create methode `clickHandler(){` and call aysncTask inside that methode.

also you can use the `onclicklistner()` method for textview *instead* of custom methode `clickHandler` as-

```
textView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }
    });
```

you can use two differnt text view for it, with linearlayout and use orientation horizontal and make both textview width and height wrap_content. place your linearlayout inside relative view, see the code below-

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/linearLayout1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="If you haven&apos;t receive verification code," />


<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:clickable="true" 
    android:onClick="clickHandler"
    android:text="tap RESEND" />
</LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```